# Arrays, Jagged arrays, multidimensional arrays Performance

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'll make it short:

```
int[,,,] Stats = new int [6, 4, 30, 10];
```

This will have 6 * 4 * 30 * 4 = 7200 elements, right?

And performance should be as good as it gets right?

If I loop through that and look for specific numbers by

```
if (x = y)
```

this should be faster than doing that with `List` or other things, right, because internally all is handled like the basic array, if I understand that all correctly?

Comment: Multi-dimensional arrays and the word performance ought not to go in one sentence.  You are paying for four bounds-checks for every single element access.  Amortizing that cost requires jagged arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are constant, vs List that is dynamic, which means when you make a new array, c# allocate memory for all those elements (in this case 7200x(int size)). 
In a list, whenever you make a new entry, c# has to update the list, allocate new memory for your new int and "connect" it to the list, therefore will be slower always.

SO, if you don't care about "wasting" memory, array will be your best choice for performance.

Comment: ok then I understood it now completely,...that was exactly my guess,.. but was not sure.    I will even use                                                           Int16[,,,] Stats =new Int16[a,b,c,d];  then